# Why doesn't the power rule work for substitutions of composite functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I came across a homework problem in my calculus 1 class where I was supposed to find the derivative of a function $y=(4x+15)^3$. This in and of itself was pretty easy, however, I thought I noticed something odd when I worked through it.
The answer to the problem is $\frac{dy}{dx}=12(4x+15)^2$, but this isn't equivalent to what you would have gotten if you had used $u$ substitution and applied the power rule such that: $$y=(4x+15)^3$$ $$u=4x+15$$$$y=u^3$$$$y=3u^2$$ $$y=3(4x+15)^2$$

Obviously this is incorrect, but conceptually, why doesn't this work? In my mind, they should produce the same answer. I did read a proof of the chain rule, which I understood just fine, but that didn't really answer the question.

Comment: Because the rule for the derivative of the composition is $(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)\cdot g'$. Also known as chain rule.

Comment: Yes, $u\in \Bbb R$, and the power rule works $\frac{dy}{du}=3u^2$, now you just need to figure out the relation between $\frac{dy}{du}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$